# How to conditionally render options in Material UI list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying to conditionally render the list items based on the user's selection but i can't seem to figure it out. I'd like to guide the users through steps in order to arrive at a final solution.  I even tried rendering a different menu but it looks like the component does not re-render once the option selected change so the menu stays the same.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

function TroubleshootingForm() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [softorHardProb, setSoftorHardProb] = useState(null);
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(1);

  const options = ['Select issue type', 'Software', 'Hardware'];

  const softwareOptions = ['Smart Assistant', 'Sounds', '3rd Party Apps', 'OPPO Clone Phone'];

  const hardwareOptions = ['Dislay', 'Battery', 'Charger', 'DOA'];

  const handleClickListItem = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
    setAnchorEl(null);
    console.log(selectedIndex);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Hardware or Software?
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <div>
            <List component="nav" aria-label="Device settings">
              <ListItem
                button
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-controls="lock-menu"
                aria-label="when device is locked"
                onClick={handleClickListItem}
              >
                <ListItemText
                  primary="When device is locked"
                  secondary={
                    selectedIndex === 1
                      ? options[selectedIndex]
                      : softwareOptions[
                          (
                            <ListItemText
                              primary="When device is locked"
                              secondary={
                                selectedIndex === 1
                                  ? options[selectedIndex]
                                  : softwareOptions[selectedIndex]
                              }
                            />
                          )
                        ]
                  }
                />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
            <Menu
              id="lock-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              keepMounted
              open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
              onClose={handleClose}
            >
              {options.map((option, index) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={option}
                  disabled={index === 0}
                  selected={index === selectedIndex}
                  onClick={event => handleMenuItemClick(event, index)}
                >
                  {option}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        {/* <Grid item xs={12}>
          {renderNextstep()}
        </Grid> */}
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default TroubleshootingForm;
```

The idea is for the user to chose options and the render the next step with other options and then so on until the final solution based on the previous selection. I added a screenshot from another app and the idea is that the current rendering of the component changes based on the selection. It starts by showing step 1 > select an option and component re-renders showing step 2 etc...

[image]

Comment: What output do you want ?

Comment: The idea is for the user to chose options and the render the next step with other options and then so on until the final solution based on the previous selection. I added a screenshot from another app and the idea is that the current rendering of the component changes based on the selection. It starts by showing step 1 > select an option and component re-renders showing step 2 etc...